# Mysql: How to convert positive value to negative while inserting

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table transaction with columns  (id, amount) all positive integers and I have another table refund with same columns but here amount is expected to be negative.
Now I want to use Insert into command to select from transaction and insert into  refund. How can I make the amount negative while inserting. following is the query that I am trying.

```
INSERT INTO refund (id,amount) 
SELECT id, amount FROM `transaction`
```

Is there any way refund.amount always takes -ve values by default.

Comment: Why not just change the sign in the `select` statement?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO refund (id,amount) 
SELECT id, (0 - amount) as amount FROM `transaction`
```

as all data in `transaction` is positive.

```
INSERT INTO refund (id,amount) 
SELECT id, (-1 * amount) as amount FROM `transaction`
```

Answer (score 12):

If you, for some reason, are not guaranteed you get a positive amount every time you insert a new row, take the absolute value and multiply it by -1

```
INSERT INTO refund (id,amount) 
SELECT id, -1 * ABS(amount) FROM `transaction`
```

Otherwise, the `ABS()` part is not needed

```
INSERT INTO refund (id,amount) 
SELECT id, -1 * amount FROM `transaction`
```

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO refund (id,amount) 
SELECT id, (amount * -1) AS amount FROM `transaction`
```

Answer (score 3):

Just multiply it by -1, do that as part of your insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO refund (id,amount) 
SELECT id,
       amount * -1 
 FROM `transaction`
```

Comment: Why not just -amount ?

Comment: My Oracle background coming through I guess.

Comment: Sorry to hear that! On a more serious note though, your solution would turn a negative value positive, which might introduce bad data, making me wonder whether I should downvote your answer.

Comment: Well he clearly states the table has all positive integers.